# Is there an easy way to make Apple Watch chime or tap hourly or more?

Tags: notifications, apple-watch

One of my planned uses of the Apple Watch was to use the Haptic technology to make a discreet tap on the hour and 20 minute marks, to gauge appointment times. But I was dumbfounded to see that Apple has not built any kind of a chime into the Apple Watch!

Does anyone know of an App or strategy that can do that without setting up hundreds of reminder or calendar notifications?

Answer (score 3):

By using the recurring event feature, you can manage them as less than 24 events. iCloud manages this efficiently. If you wish to delete one, you can delete all future events at one time.

### Creating a recurring calendar event

Create a calendar event for your first Chime with these settings:

- **name**: **Chime**
- **starts**: **4:00**
- **ends**: **4:01**
- **repeat**: **Every Day**
- **alert**: **At time of event**

[image: calendar event settings]

Since there are 24 hours in the day, you will need to **create 24 of them** for **each hour** in a single day.

**Uncheck** that calendar in your Calendar app to hide it so you don't have to see it:

[image: calendar unchecked hidden]

Perfect! Now your calendar still looks nice and clean.

### Deleting a Chime

If you want to delete a chime, **check** the Chime calendar to make it visible again. Select an event and press the **Delete** key:

[image: delete event]

Click **Delete All** in the prompt:

[image: all events]

Now your Chime is removed from all future days:

[image: event removed]

Comment: By using the recurring event feature, you can manage them as less than 24 events. iCloud manages this efficiently. If you wish to delete one, you can delete all future events at one time: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/fWK0qTh.png)

Comment: Edited the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: This answer is not very elegant. Creating 24 events by hand is terribly hacky though there does not seem to be a better one.

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature in watch OS 6 that allows you to play a chime on the hour, half hour or 15 minute mark.

On your watch go to Settings->Accessibility->Chimes

From there you can turn the feature on, set the schedule (15 minutes, 30 minutes or on the hour) and set the sound (Bells or Birds). If your watch is silenced you'll get a taptic alert instead.

Answer (score -1):

There is an hourly chime app that says it works with Apple Watch, and I am currently looking for one as well, so I'm trying it out. I just installed it, but if you don't already have it it's Diii - hourly chime and custom sound alarm reminder by 推荐精品.  There's a free version, or the paid version is $2.99, which I think is rather steep, but if you have the free version,which  is pretty lame, because you'll only have a limited amount of sounds, which you'll likely hear on your phone  if it's unlocked.  You can't set it to chime on the 20 minute mark though, only on the hour and the half hour. 
https://appsto.re/us/q8bS7.i

Comment: Please describe how you can use the product and disclose your affiliation with this product (if no affiliation do state)